# Assign Ansible variable to dynamic array of JSON objects using Jinja2 template

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2

I have an Ansible variable called port_mapping that is assigned an array of JSON objects. I want to create this array of JSON objects in a dynamic way using Jinja2 templates.

```
    ports_mapping:
        - name: Et1
          port_number: 1
          type: access
          vlan: 1
        - name: Et2
          port_number: 2
          type: access
          vlan: 1
        - name: Et3
          port_number: 3
          type: access
          vlan: 1
        - name: Et4
          port_number: 4
          type: access
          vlan: 1
```

Here's what I am trying to do and it's throwing errors, I think it's reading the spacing wrong so it doesn't interpret it as an array of json objects. In this example, I want to create 30 JSON objects.

`ports_mapping: "{{ lookup('template', 'switchports.j2') }}"`

**switchports.j2**

```
{% for i in range(1,30) %}
- name: Et{{ i }}
  port_number: {{ i }}
  type: access
  vlan: 1
{% endfor %}
```

**Can someone please recommend how I can achieve what I am trying to do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the template is string

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: ports_mapping
    - debug:
        var: ports_mapping|type_debug
```

give (the range limited to 2 items)

```yaml
  ports_mapping: |-
    - name: Et1
      port_number: 1
      type: access
      vlan: 1
    - name: Et2
      port_number: 2
      type: access
      vlan: 1

  ports_mapping|type_debug: str
```

Use the filter *from_yaml* to convert the string to the list

```yaml
ports_mapping: "{{ lookup('template', 'switchports.j2')|from_yaml }}"
```

Then the tasks above give

```yaml
  ports_mapping:
  - name: Et1
    port_number: 1
    type: access
    vlan: 1
  - name: Et2
    port_number: 2
    type: access
    vlan: 1

  ports_mapping|type_debug: list
```

Comment: Thanks so much! You're a live-saver